# Save Bandwidth: Turn Video Into Audio JavaScript

Tags: javascript

While writing software, I like to listen to latest hits of music from my browser on aghaniaghani.com  which is a TV channel that live-streams on its website the music video clips. I only care about the music though.

Is there a JavaScript script that could disable the video on the page (in the website, it's `<video>` but keep the audio playing so that some bandwidth could be saved and there will no longer be a need to buffer the video frames?

Is this doable? How do I get started?

EDIT: The website is http://www.aghaniaghani.com/ the `video src` is   `blob:http://www.aghaniaghani.com/04f130aa-3703-469b-8985-5fc891dc8c68`

Comment: What is the `MIME` type of the video? Have you tried setting the `<video>` `src` at `src` of `<audio>` element?

Comment: It's very unlikely that they send the audio separately so no, I don't think it can be done.

Comment: @JJJ It should be possible. A video has an audio track and video track.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, it's possible to separate them while you're receiving the stream but the OP's goal is to save bandwidth by having the web site send only the audio data. You can't download only the audio track unless the web site supports it, and it's very unlikely that it does.

Comment: @guest271314 how do I do that?

Comment: Locate the `src` of the `<video>` which you are trying to play audio from. Try creating an `html` document and including an `<audio>` element with `src` set to the `src` you retrieved from `<video>` element.

Comment: @JJJ Good point. Would need an example URL to try different approaches.

Comment: @user640853 Can you include an example URL from a `src` of `<video>` element at Question?

Comment: @user640853 At first glance it does not appear that there are any `<video>` elements at linked page. Only multiple ajax calls being made.

Comment: @guest271314 check updated question

Comment: Where did you get the URL at updated Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I inspected the source of video and I got that

Comment: @guest271314 `Ctrl+Shift+C` on the video and see the source code of it

Comment: What video? Is the video within an `<iframe>`? `Blob URL`'s are tied to the `document` where the `Blob` is created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136813/discussion-between-user640853-and-guest271314).